# Python | MemoryError: Unable to allocate 527. GiB for an array with shape (19, 3724775711) and data type float64

Tags: python

first and foremost, I hope that I haven't posted this in the wrong section. This is literally my first question posted on this forum. I am also not a software developer. My academic background is in finance and I am a self-taught scripter.

Problem - I am trying to concatenate two BIG csv files using python. File one is 334,482 KB and File two is 493,487KB. I have read the csv files into Python and am getting an error.

```
finalData = pd.merge(data1,data2,on = 'isin', how = 'inner')
```

Very straight forward call. My plan is to then write 'finalData' to csv. Unfortunately, I am getting....

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 527. GiB for an array with shape (19, 3724775711) and data 
type float64
```

I have a decent setup on my machine with an i9, 64GB of memory, and a GPU. Any ideas on how I can get this to work? Any and all help is much appreciated - just please keep in mind that I am not a software person and I need everything spelled out for me to the 'T'.

Comment: It is saying you're trying to create an array of 19 columns (that's probably ok) and 3724775711 rows with float64 values, which indeed is around 566 GB or 527 GiB. Are you sure you want to `merge` the dataframes, or are you looking for `append` or `concat`?

Comment: Fair question. data1 has a total of 33 columns and data2 has 31 columns, where 17 are the same across both data1 and data2. Each row represents a new date. Of the 31 columns in data2, I want to use the 'isin' and 'date'  to cross reference with the correct 'isin' and 'date' in data1 and add the 13 columns that I need from data2 to data1. Given, what I have read, append may work but how do I do that based on 'isin' and 'date'? From an SQL perspective, I am looking for an inner join on 'isin' and 'date'. Hope that this makes sense.